# What's a good tag for priesthood of all believers?

Tags: discussion, tags

What is a good alternative tag for priesthood of all believers? It exceeds the 25 character limit for tags. Does [universal-priesthood](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/universal-priesthood) work? Do they mean the same?

Answer (score 3):

I like [universal-priesthood](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/universal-priesthood).

I know that there's a tag limit, so I don't know if [priesthood-of-all-believers](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/priesthood-of-all-believers) would be too long or not.

Whichever is decided, we need to make a synonym from one to the other.

Comment: priesthood-of-all-believers is too long.

Comment: Aah.  Well, I guess universal-priesthood would get it.  Or just priesthood.  *POAB* and *priesthood-of-all-belie* would be bad.  ;)

Comment: I actually thought about recommending poab, but I figured the joke would be too hard to detect.